# Splitting an IRIS db to multiple drives

Tags: intersystems-iris

I'm looking for a way to have an IRIS db distributed over several (hw) drives.
Without touching the internal data structures (e.g. mapping) !
Are there any options in file systems to achieve this "splitting" or "appending"
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input by Alexander Pettitt · Apr 9, 2021

Death to extents :)

I work in Unix where LVM and mount points would make this easy but it looks like Windows has mount points.

[Windows mount point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/assign-a-mount-point-folder-path-to-a-drive)